# Indexing for SQL table which uses multiple combination of set of columns in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL table which is only loaded once (no update/insert/delete) and thereafter it will be used in report. The report has multiple sql queries written on this table and the queries are running for long time. I am trying to make use of indexing but stuck with following issue.

The table has two sets of columns (col1,col2,col3 & col7,col8,col9) and these columns are used in where clause,  group bys in report queries in different combination.

for example:
select col1,col7,count(*)
from table
group by col1,col7

select col1,col8,count(*)
from table
group by col1,col8

and so on. The query will always have two columns used in the group by or filter. If I try to apply index on individual columns (index on col1, index on col2 etc) then the index is not used for the query. Only when I apply index for the particular combination that is used in the query (example composite index on col1,col4) then the index gets used.

The table has around 10 columns (two sets of 5) which can be used in combination and I dont want to create composite index for each possible combination as the table is large.

What would be a correct indexing solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16

it is built exactly for your type of scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use column store index but one set of columns (col7,8,9) is of nvarchar(max). The documentation in here says not to use nvarchar(max) columns in column store index. Any other solution I can try?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can use a non-clustered columnstore index .. I assume you won't do aggregations and reports out of the nvarchar(max) columns .. (and if so, you might want to reduce their size and fit them into the columnstore index)

Comment: Those nvarchar(max) columns are used in aggregation and also displayed in report. Unfortunately we can't put a size limit on this column as rarely they will value more than 8000. So if include just the other columns (non varchar(max)) columns in non-clustered columnstore index, will it still benefit the query if it has mix of non nvarchar(max) and other columns in gorupby or where clause?

Comment: Yeah .. you may/will see benefits depending on your workload. 

However I would suggest moving the nvarchar columns into normalized columns (if at all possible). This would give you by far the best benefit, to the expense of some work for you.